# How to call an AJAX function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to call GetAllProperties() function during page loading instead of calling the GetAllProperties() function after page is fully loaded.

I tried window.onload = GetAllProperties; but it didn't work

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload = GetAllProperties;


    function GetAllProperties() {    
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/Home/GetAllProperties',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.list.length > 0) {
                    console.log(response.list)
                    var $data = $('<table id="mytable"  class="table  table-striped"> </table>');
                    var header = "<thead><tr><th>Property Name</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>";
                    $data.append(header);
                    $.each(response.list, function (i, row) {
                        var $row = $('<tr/>');
                        $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.PropertyName));
                        $hidden = $(' <input type="hidden" name="hid" value= "' + row.PropertyId + '">');
                        $row.append($hidden);
                        $editButton = $("<button class='editbtn' id='mybtn'>Edit</button>");    
                        $row.append($editButton);
                        $deleteButton = $("<button class='deletebtn' id='delbtn'>Delete</button>");    
                        $row.append($deleteButton);
                        $data.append($row);
                    });        
                    $("#MyDiv").empty();
                    $("#MyDiv").append($data);
                }
                else {

                }
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert('Error! Please try again.' + r.responseText);
                console.log(r);    
            }
        });    
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: This question is the same as the one you asked previously. If you want to add more detail to the question, please use the `edit` button. Also note that the code you have appears to work fine. If it doesn't meet your requirements, please clearly explain *why* that is

Answer (score 3):

You are using jQuery already, so why not bind an event listener to `window` with it?

```js
$(window).on("load", GetAllProperties);

function GetAllProperties() {
    alert("loaded");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it is even working without:

```js
window.onload = GetAllProperties;

function GetAllProperties() {
    alert("loaded");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... but why the table populate after page load?

Comment: You know that Ajax is asynchronous, or? This means the page will keep loading while the function is been executed. It is possible that the page finished loading before Ajax request has finished. @Lucy

Comment: No, I don't .. it would be better write a very simple code